# Cant send large attachments from iOS using Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, ios, attachment

Some of my users are having issues sending emails with attachments from iOS devices but the same works fein from desktop versions. There seems to be a link to the size of the attachment, as an example 8mb files are causing an issue where 1mb files are fine.

I have checked maxRequestLengths in config files and they look to be well over the 8mb size. I'm just looking for a little guidance to point me in the right direction.

Any help is much appreciated.

Environment is Exchange 2013 SP1 running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: YES! Thank you for the tip, that was exactly the issue! Many thanks for the help. I didn't think iOS would use ActiveSync as the back-end protocol so disregarded the configs in the sync folder, oh well... Live and learn!